# Regular expression to match the last integer in a string with php and javascript

Tags: php, javascript, regex, anchor, digit

I need to match the last integer in a string and capture possible elements before and after the last integer, assuming that the string can be composed of a single integer or a combination of text and/or integers.
Let say that $str can be:

- '123' -> '' - 123 - ''
- 'abc 123' -> 'abc ' - 123
- 'abc 123 def' -> 'abc ' - 123 - ' def'
- 'abc 123 def 456' -> 'abc 123 def ' - 456
- etc.

I expected that the following piece of code in php would do the job:

```
$str = 'abc 123 def 456 ghi';
preg_match('/(.*)(\d+)(\D*)$/', $str, $matches);
echo 'Matches = ' . implode(' : ', $matches);
```

But the (\d+) is picking up only one digit:

```
 Matches = abc 123 def 456 ghi : abc 123 def 45 : 6 :  ghi
```

While I was expecting:

```
 Matches = abc 123 def 456 ghi : abc 123 def  : 456 :  ghi
```

I get the same behavior in Javascript.
The (.*) is that greedy to impinge on (\d+)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wouldn't using **just** `/(\d+)/` do the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can completely avoid the .* as the "\D*$" at the end of the pattern would make sure it is the last number.

It is also recommended that you don't add unnecessary parenthesis and only get what you really need. That is to say that you could do the following to only get the last number:

```
preg_match('/(\d+)\D*$/', $str, $matches);
```

If you do need the match on the other portions of the string, though, and the number you are looking for will be its own word you could add to that regexp the \b parameter before the (\d+) so that the (.*) won't greedily consume part of your number. i.e.:

```
preg_match('/(.*)\b(\d+)(\D*)$/', $str, $matches);
```

Comment: Actually, this would also work and the integer can be mixed with chars: /(.*\D)(\d+)(\D*)$/ so with $str = 'abc 123 def456ghi', I would get the 'abc 123 def' - 456 - 'ghi'.

Answer (score 6):

Why not `/(\d+)\D*$/`? That way, the only capturing group is the integer.

Btw, when I'm working with regexes, i usually use http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: I should have stated that I also need to capture the possible elements before and after the last integer.

Comment: @Raphael: If you just need to capture **all** numbers, use `preg_match('/(\d+)/', $str, $matches);`. You then have all integers in `$matches[1]`.

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript:

```
$str = 'abc 123 def 456';
$matches = $str.match(/\d+/g);
$lastInt = $matches[$matches.length-1];
```

In PHP

```
$str = 'abc 123 def 456';
preg_match_all('/(\d+)/', $str, $matches);
$lastInt = end($matches);
echo 'Last integer = ' . $lastInt;
```

Comment: `g` is not a valid modifier in PHP as far as I can tell?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much of PHP regular expressions. Could you please fix the code?

Comment: I don't know what `g` would do in JS.

Comment: Means global: Selects more occurences of this expression

Comment: Guess that's what [`preg_match_all()`](http://www.php.net/preg_match_all) (a completely different function) is for then. `preg_match_all('/(\d+)/', $str, $matches);` would be your equivalent.

Comment: Ok, I'll fix it. Thank you :)

Comment: Also, php has no `$array.length`, that's what `count($array)` does, otherwise it looks ok. (Fix your $matches <-> $matchs typo though :D)

Comment: You can also just use `end($matches)` to get the last element.

Comment: What a shame, a lot of stupid errors. Thank you very much guy

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for ya...

```
(\d+)(?!.*\d)
```

Comment: Indeed, but I also need to capture the possible text before and after the last integer. I should have stated in my post.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cach the **last** integer, you should use the $ at the end of the regular expression.

Try with `/(\d+)$/` in both languages.